# How to get any user details from facebook api

Tags: javascript

How to find user details by using his/her email ID or mobile number from Facebook? I want to get user details on my website using my app id access.

Please help me out this.

Comment: Have you found any solution for getting user details by his/him phone number or email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You need his facebook ID or his facebook name.

```
var fields = [
      'id',
      'name',
      'first_name',
      'middle_name',
      'last_name',
      'gender']


FB.api('/{insertIDhere}', {fields: fields}, function(details) {
  // output the response

});
```

Or take this code from the FB Api Documentation

```
FB.api(
"/{user-id}",
function (response) {
  if (response && !response.error) {
    /* handle the result */
  }
}
);
```

to login you need something like this :

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        //login successfull
    } else {
       //anything else
    }
}, {scope: 'public_profile,email,user_friends'});
```

If you are logged in you could use something like this:

```
FB.api(
    "/me?fields=id,name,picture.redirect(false).type(large)",
    function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            facebookId              = response.id;
            facebookName            = response.name;
            facebookProfilePicture  = response.picture.data.url;
            callback(facebookUser);
        }else{

        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but how would i got his/her FB id

Comment: You need to login and get the user details.

Comment: it means i have to force user for login..?

Comment: If you dont have the facebook id by yourself you have to get it from the user by let him logging in

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Searching by email or phone is not possible.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#search